# Regular Expressions strip values

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

From the string "A123.456C-456.789F987321" I need to return

- A123.456
- C-456.789
- F987321

This can either be as 3 individual calls as "A" (or "C" or "F" followed by any decimal number or decimal point or sign ("+" or "-") until the next non-numeric (or decimalpoint or sign) character, or a more generic call of any letter followed by any number or decimal until the next non-numeric (or decimalpoint or sign)

Thanks

Edit:

For clarity what regular expression should I use to in terms of X to return

```
123.456 Where X = "A"
-456.789 Where X = "C"
987321 Where X = "F"
```

From the string "A123.456C-456.789F987321"

Comment: Please be clear on question.

Comment: @KarthikAMR Edited For clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one :**

```
(\w\-?[\d\.]+)
```

**Explanation :**

```
\w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
\-? matches the character - literally
       Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
[\d\.]+ match a single character present in the list below
       Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\d match a digit [0-9]
\. matches the character . literally

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

**Demo :**

http://regex101.com/r/iG6lD1

Answer (score 0):

You are doing overlapping regex matching. Your regex will be :

```
(?=([A-Z][^A-Z]+))
```

Here it is picking a capital letter and after than non capital letters as a group.

You can easily modify this example as per your need(alphanumeric with other characters!)

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
        var regVal  = "A123.456C-456.789F987321";

        string pattern =@"([A-Z][-]*[0-9|.]+)";
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(regVal, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);

}
```

output is :

A123.456

C-456.789

F987321